# implicit policy evaluation failed - ... requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am getting this error while creating channel

```
implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied
```

Here is my congigtx.yaml file

```
Organizations:
- &OrdererOrg
    Name: OrdererOrg
    ID: OrdererMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/vrs.com/msp
    # AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
    OrdererEndpoints:
        - orderer.vrs.com:7050

    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

- &Excise
    Name: ExciseMSP
    ID: ExciseMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/excise.vrs.com/msp
    # AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer0.excise.vrs.com
          Port: 7051
    
    

    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('ExciseMSP.admin', 'ExciseMSP.peer', 'ExciseMSP.client')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('ExciseMSP.admin', 'ExciseMSP.client')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('ExciseMSP.admin')"
        Endorsement:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('ExciseMSP.peer')"

- &Manufacturer
        Name: ManufacturerMSP
        ID: ManufacturerMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/manufacturer.vrs.com/msp
        # AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.manufacturer.vrs.com
              Port: 9051
    
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ManufacturerMSP.admin','ManufacturerMSP.peer','ManufacturerMSP.client','ExciseMSP.admin','ExciseMSP.peer','ExciseMSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ManufacturerMSP.admin', 'ManufacturerMSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ManufacturerMSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ManufacturerMSP.peer')"
- &Dealer
        Name: DealerMSP
        ID: DealerMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dealer.vrs.com/msp
        # AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.dealer.vrs.com
              Port: 11051
    
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('DealerMSP.admin','DealerMSP.peer','DealerMSP.client','ExciseMSP.admin','ExciseMSP.peer','ExciseMSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('DealerMSP.admin', 'DealerMSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('DealerMSP.admin')"
            # Endorsement:
            #     Type: Signature
            #     Rule: "OR('DealerMSP.peer')"

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V2_0: true

    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V2_0: true

    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V2_0: true
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    Capabilities:
          <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
    ACLs: &ACLsDefault
        lscc/ChaincodeExists: /Channel/Application/Readers
        lscc/GetDeploymentSpec: /Channel/Application/Readers
        lscc/GetChaincodeData: /Channel/Application/Readers
        lscc/GetInstantiatedChaincodes: /Channel/Application/Readers
        qscc/GetChainInfo: /Channel/Application/Readers
        qscc/GetBlockByNumber: /Channel/Application/Readers
        qscc/GetBlockByHash: /Channel/Application/Readers
        qscc/GetTransactionByID: /Channel/Application/Readers
        qscc/GetBlockByTxID: /Channel/Application/Readers
        cscc/GetConfigBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers
        cscc/GetConfigTree: /Channel/Application/Readers
        cscc/SimulateConfigTreeUpdate: /Channel/Application/Readers
        peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/Writers
        peer/ChaincodeToChaincode: /Channel/Application/Readers
        event/Block: /Channel/Application/Readers
        event/FilteredBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers
    Policies: &ApplicationDefaultPolicies
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    Addresses:
        - orderer.vrs.com:7050
    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: orderer.vrs.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/vrs.com/orderers/orderer.vrs.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/vrs.com/orderers/orderer.vrs.com/tls/server.crt
    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
    Policies: &OrdererDefaultPolicies
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Organizations:


Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:
    Genesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            MainConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Excise
                    - *Manufacturer
                    - *Dealer
                    
    Channel:
        Consortium: MainConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Excise 
                - *Manufacturer 
                - *Dealer 
                               
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Comment: How were you creating a channel, could you share the steps you executed and the results, please?

Comment: the issue has been resolved. thank you